# Form that uploads images immediately when selected

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I have a form that has a few normal text inputs, but also allows image uploads.

I need a system that, when the user selects the images they want to upload, it immediately uploads them (without pressing the submit button for the form). The rest of the form (the normal text inputs), however, require a manual click on the submit button. I believe this is how Facebook does it as well (in case you don't get what I'm saying).

*I'm not asking how to program this, I'm asking how I should organize this, since I need to somehow make a connection between the submitted form data and the uploaded images.*

I was thinking of doing the following:

- Create a hidden input with a random integer.
- When the images are uploaded, they would be uploaded to some directory like `/uploads/<USER_ID>/<RAND_NUM>/`.
- Then, when the rest of the form is submitted, it would check if that directory exists (meaning that images were uploaded) and then make the correlation there.

I noticed that Laravel automatically adds a CSRF random token to the form, however, this token does *not* change for each new refresh, so I'm guessing that I'd have to create another token specifically for my needs.

Is this a suggested approach to this problem or are there better ways to do it?

Comment: I would say your pretty much on point. Just hash the filename+timestamp and use that to rename the file when you upload it. Pass that data back to the form and put it in a hidden input.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this using [Dropezone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/). Following is the code that I used for uploading image in my code:

```
$(".template-picture").dropzone({
    url: "{{ UPLOAD_URL}}",
    maxFiles: 1,
    paramName: 'file',
    success: function (file, response) {
        // store response in hidden field
    },
    sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
        formData.append("_token", $('[name="_token"]').val());
    }
});
```

On server side. you can receive file and store at the location and return the path of the file that you want to store in the DB and set it in the hidden field in success function in above code.

Comment: I'm already using dropzone.js, but again, I'm not asking HOW to do this, I'm asking how to ORGANIZE it.

Comment: That's what I am trying to suggest, you need a hidden field that stores the path to the file. and the upload action returns that path which is stored in the hidden field which then will be submitted with the rest of the form values.

Comment: if you need random number that can also be generated on server side and pretended to the file path that is being returned, or you can pass that random number in the sending function.